# Joining Two Tables to find Non Matching Info

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Sorry for all of the edits, but this seems to be giving me the opposite of what I need.  I'm open for any suggestions!

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warehouselogin LEFT OUTER JOIN warehousedatains on warehouselogin.instructor_password = warehousedatains.instructor_password && warehousedatains.unitnumber='$unitnumber' && warehousedatains.year='$year' && warehousedatains.outcomenumber='$outcomenumbercheck' WHERE warehousedatains.instructor_password IS NOT NULL GROUP BY warehouselogin.InstructorName ASC");
```

---

OK guys...I'm still having some trouble, and after fighting with this for a while, I'm asking for help again.

This query is working...it gives me any instructors in the left table that do not exist in the right table for the submitted year.

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warehouselogin LEFT OUTER JOIN warehousedatains on warehouselogin.instructor_password = warehousedatains.instructor_password && warehousedatains.year='$year' WHERE warehousedatains.instructor_password IS NULL GROUP BY warehouselogin.InstructorName ASC");
```

However, when I tried to compare additional submitted variables, it will not work.

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warehouselogin LEFT OUTER JOIN warehousedatains on warehouselogin.instructor_password = warehousedatains.instructor_password && warehousedatains.year='$year' && warehousedatains.unitnumber='$unitnumber' && warehousedatains.outcomenumber='$outcomenumbercheck' WHERE warehousedatains.instructor_password IS NULL GROUP BY warehouselogin.InstructorName ASC");
```

I need to match these additional values.  Otherwise, I get instructors from every department.  What am I missing here?  Thanks so much for any help!

---

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.  I was finally able to get the query below to work by putting the year variable statement directly above the query ($year="$_POST[year]".  I really appreciate the help!

---

I'm trying to join two tables based on the `instructor_password` field and echo any non matches.  Basically, I'm looking for passwords found in the first table (`warehouselogin`) that are not found in the second table (`warehousedatains`) for the submitted year.  I've done this before using a join similar to below, but I'm missing something.  This currently finds nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM warehouselogin
LEFT OUTER JOIN warehousedatains on warehouselogin.instructor_password = warehousedatains.instructor_password && warehousedatains.year='?'
WHERE warehousedatains.instructorpassword IS NULL
ORDER BY warehousedatains.InstructorName ASC
```

Where the `?` in `year='?'` has a specific value.

Comment: Can you echo the actual query, so without the question mark

Comment: @Strawberry I added the question mark, in the original post this is a PHP term with a variable instead of the question mark

Comment: Fine.  Can you echo the actual query, so without the question mark, or the php variable.

Comment: [Bangs head against wall.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM warehouselogin 
          WHERE warehouselogin.instructor_password 
          NOT IN
          (SELECT warehousedatains.instructor_password FROM warehousedatains)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  Can you tell me how to correctly use this with a PHP query?

Comment: Did yo try putting in $r = mysql_query('sqlquery')

Comment: Thank you.  I finally got it to work...just had a missing quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @misthacoder, I was finally able to get this query working and give me the results I needed in a PHP script.  I wanted to share in case anyone else has a similar problem.  Thanks so much for everyone who tried to help.

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warehouselogin WHERE unitnumber='$unitnumber' && warehouselogin.instructor_password NOT IN (SELECT warehousedatains.instructor_password FROM warehousedatains WHERE unitnumber='$unitnumber' && outcomenumber='$outcomenumbercheck')");
```